# svn update locks up on folder that no longer exists

Tags: svn, locking

When I go to update, I keep getting a locking error on a folder that no longer exists.  My first thought is to go use svn-cleanup to fix whatever has broken.  Instead, cleanup throws an error also:

> Problem running log
>   svn: In directory "C:\xxxxx\xxx\"
>   svn: Error rocessing command "append" in "C:\xxxxx\xxx\"
>   svn: Missing "xyz" attribute in C:\xxxxx\xxx\"

Any ideas to clean this mess up besides re-downloading the entire project again?

Comment: Getting a clean checkout and just dropping your changes over the top is probably gonna be easier; you should be able to export from your working directory even if you can't update.

In the future, try to avoid deleting folders from the filesystem directly when they're part of SVN repositories.

Comment: I think you're right, you just can't mess with the file structures unless you are using svn to remove/add.  It just doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use TortoiseSVN, and for some reason this happens quite frequently (3-4X per year).  The quickest solution for us is to just delete the folder and check it out again.  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
svn update
```

which will get the missing folder back.

Comment: My first comment was that I tried to update and got a locking error.  I think svn got really unhappy when I deleted a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a [link](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=1074741) from the tortisesvn forum.  It basically said to pull the project again.  I'm open to know another way to fix it if anyone has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you delete the parent folder that contains the missing folder, or is that too big?

After deleting the parent folder then do another svn update.  This has worked for me in the past for your same problem.   Luckily for me my parent folder that contained the problem folder was small.

Comment: This is at the root, so deleting the parent directory deletes the project.  I've done that in the past also.

Answer (score 0):

you might try to run Revert on it.

Comment: That didn't work, it gave me a dir-props error.  I think I'm going to just smoke it and pull a new project (copy over the changes)

Answer (score 0):

I would try pulling the sources again and doing a directory wide diff using [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/). This should allow you to reapply the changes you made to any files and correctly remove folders using *svn remove*.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, I usually delete the offending directory (not the whole project) and then run `svn update` to pull down the missing bits.

If that doesn't work, then I pull the whole thing down again.